# Is there a way to highlight all instances of the variable under the cursor?

Tags: front-end

Many code editors (such as MATLAB's) can highlight all occurrences of the variable which is under the cursor. Is this possible in Mathematica?

For example I create a variable, then I use it many times, and when I place the cursor in that variable, then every place where I use it, it highlights. So, you can see the variable where I use it in all code.

Comment: I edited this post to make sure it won't be mistaken for an (off-topic) MATLAB question. In reality it has nothing to do with MATLAB.

Comment: `highlight all occurrences of the variable` btw, for me, I find this is the most annoying feature of any editor, In Matlab, I turn this off first thing when I install Matlab. It is OK to have it when you want to use it, but not as a default all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica's notebook interface does not have this feature. Personally, I do not think this feature is a very good fit for a notebook interface.  But of course, sometimes we don't do interactive exploration in a notebook, but write larger programs (code meant to be used many times) in a plain text file (`.m` or `.wl`, package files). The feature makes much more sense in that context, and there are IDEs which support it.

Here's a screenshot from [the Wolfram Language plugin for IntelliJ](https://wlplugin.halirutan.de/):

[image]

Notice that it understands local variables: only those instances of "cutoff" are highlighted which are truly the same.

I might be wrong, but as I recall the Wolfram Workbench (an Eclipse plugin) also has this capability. General purpose editors such as VS Code can also do it, but they won't be able to distinguish a local and a global instance of a variable.